# Bootstrap form input field and button Unclickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form in which there are two input fields and one button. First input field is working properly but the second input field and the button are both unclickable.

**Note:** Following Stack Overflow regulations, all codepen links are followed by codes. So the post might look unnecessary long.

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/ZyLLVL/) for the page. See code below.

**HTML**`

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" id="row-masthead">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div id="logo-enclosure">
                    <img src="justlogo.png" alt="" id="logo">
                </div>

                <div id="masthead-welcome-note"> 
                    <h1>Wow Your Customers</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="masthead-welcome-note-small">with exceptional customer service. Try Hiver!</div>

                <div id="form-enclosure">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input-email">Enter email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input-phone">Enter phone</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-phone">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">GET STARTED FOR FREE</button>
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="row-reviews"> 
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <!-- column 12-->

                <div id="image-quote-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div id="circular-image-container">
                        <img src="bean.png" id="circular-image">
                    </div>
                    <div id="quote">
                        Hiver is hands down the best way for us to collaborate on Gmail. Managing our scheduling has never been easier.

                        <footer><strong>Christian Leybold - (General Partner, eVentures.vc)</strong></footer>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div id="close-quote-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

        </div>

        <div class="row">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 0;
}

#row-masthead{
    background-color: #069A78;
    height: 27vh;
}

#logo-enclosure{
    background-color: ;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}

#logo{
    width: 120px;
    height: 48px;   
}

#masthead-welcome-note h1{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    font-size: 42px;
    background-color: ;
}
#masthead-welcome-note-small{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: -0.5%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    background-color: ;
}

#form-enclosure{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6%;
    top: 48%;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #D1D1D1; 
    border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

#form-enclosure > form > div > label{
    color: #B0A9A9;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#form-enclosure > form > div > input{
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border-color: #ECECEC;
}

#form-enclosure > form > button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.8em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #E87A06;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#row-reviews{
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;

    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
}

#row-reviews > div{   /* this is the column inside the row */
    height: 100%;     /* the column should take full height of the row ie  30vh */
    background-color: ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}

#image-quote-container{
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 52%;
    height: 90%; 
    position: relative; /*relative parent*/

    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
}

i.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 4%;
    float: left;
    width: 3%; /* to prevent jumping effect*/

    /*background-color: plum;
    border: 1px solid black;*/
}

#circular-image-container{
    margin-left: 3%;    /* moving bean image right from open quote*/
    margin-top: 6%;     /* moving bean image bottom from its reference point ie parent div*/
    margin-right: 5%;   /* maintain distance between image and texts on the right*/ 
    float: left;
}

#circular-image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}

#quote{
    margin-top: 7%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #7f8c8d; /* grey color for text */       

    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

footer{
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

#close-quote-container{
    width: 3%;
    height: 90%; 
    position: relative; /* relative parent for absolute close quote*/

    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
}

i.fa-quote-right{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

`

However, when I put the form separately in => [Another pen link](https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/Qgddey/) it seems to work fine (i.e same code but here input fields and buttons are clickable). See code below:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="form-enclosure">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input-email">Enter email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input-phone">Enter phone</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-phone">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">GET STARTED FOR FREE</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: plum;
}

#form-enclosure{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 30%;
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #D1D1D1; 
    border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

#form-enclosure > form > div > label{
    color: #B0A9A9;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#form-enclosure > form > div > input{
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border-color: #ECECEC;
}

#form-enclosure > form > button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.8em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #E87A06;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I fail to understand this behaviour. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the size to `col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`(This measurement is just for testing, you must identify the measurement that is required for you)
The element highlighted in the image is getting overlayed over the input text element and the button that makes both the elements unclickable

[image]

**Updated Answer:**
When you add position: absolute, the element is taken out from the normalflow.
So other elements takes precedence over elements with absolute positioning. There is precedence in overlay for normal flow elements over absolute elements. You can also use z-index to resolve this issue. 

add z-index: 1; for the element that has position:absolute. This will solve your problem too. i think this will be easier than the approach which i mentioned at first

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had no idea that improper col size could have such an effect. Please correct my understanding a bit. I felt that, since the div containing the form had `position: absolute` property, it would lose its space in the DOM and just float above all. My question is, why should the column size effect a div that is floating and not part of the DOM anymore?

Comment: @SwagnikDutta please check my updated answer. Also accept the answer if it solves your problem.